# what is the way to change a state's value in concurrent tabs using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, jwt, local-storage

In my website, I implemented *Authentication system using MongoDB*. When I do successfully Log in to the website, a token is passed from server. As a result, current tab identify the log in process and is authenticated.

***But the concurrently opened tabs are still logged out.***  In the case of log out same thing happens. (only the current tab is effected by the value of token from local storage.)

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const API = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1';
const useAuth= () => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const [changeState, setChangeState] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
            const jwt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));
            // no jwt means no user logged in
            if (jwt === null) {
                setUser({});
                setIsLoading(false);
                return;
            }
            //decode jwt
            const decoded = jwt_decode(jwt);
            setUser({ ...decoded });
        }, [changeState])
    
    
       const authenticate = (token) => {
            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                localStorage.setItem('jwt', JSON.stringify(token));
            }
            setChangeState(!changeState)
        }
    
    
       const login = (user) => {
            //when successfully logged in,  authenticate(token)  is called
            return fetch(`${API}/user/login`, {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(user)
            })
        };
    
        
        const logOut = () => {
            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
                setUser({});
            }
        }

return {
        user,
        register,
        login,
        authenticate,
        logOut,
        setUser,
    }
}
export default useAuth;
```

I want to change the value of ***user*** state in all the tabs at the same time. So all opened tabs can identify whether **Log In** or **Log Out** is done.

Comment: Use the [`useLocalStorage` hook](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/). Although I would recommend logging the user in from a top level component rather than from within child tab components

Comment: Hi, Can you add the code where you are utilizing the useAuth hook as well?